# How to get longitude and latitude data from an array inside object and display them as google map link on output

Tags: javascript, html, json

How can I get the coordinates and display them as a Google Maps link on the output? I couldn't figure it out and any advice would be much helpful. Thank you. API data content is linked as a pic on below.
[`

```js
function searchCity(city) {
    //var r=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    document.getElementById("searchvalues").innerHTML = "Search by City" + "<br>";
    //structure table
    var output = "<tr><th> Location </th><th> City </th><th> Phone </th><th> Vaccine Type </th><th> Map Link</th></tr>";
    var searchid;
    var map = obj.point{coordinates:[]};;
    for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        var obj = r[i];
        searchid = obj.city.toUpperCase(); 
        if (searchid.startsWith(city.toUpperCase())) {
            output += "<tr><td>";
            output += obj.location;
            output += "</td><td>";
            output += obj.city;
            output += "</td><td>";
            output += obj.phone;
            output += "</td><td>";
            output += obj.vaccinetype;
            output += "</td><td>";
            output += <a href='https:www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=' + map + ' target=_blank'> Click here to see map </a>;
            output += "</td></tr>";            
            
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML = output;
}
```

`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oaNW.png)

Comment: I added the image for json data as a link on above.

Answer (score 0):

`obj.point.coordinates` try it

it is an array

`var map = obj.point{coordinates:[]};;` always don't change, you can set coordinates to link same as :

```
let coordinate = obj.point.coordinates.reverse().toString();
output += <a href='https:www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=' + coordinate + ' target=_blank'> Click here to see map </a>;
```

It same as :

```
function searchCity(city) {
//var r=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
document.getElementById("searchvalues").innerHTML = "Search by City" + "<br>";
//structure table
var output = "<tr><th> Location </th><th> City </th><th> Phone </th><th> Vaccine Type </th><th> Map Link</th></tr>";
var searchid;
for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    var obj = r[i];
    searchid = obj.city.toUpperCase(); 
    if (searchid.startsWith(city.toUpperCase())) {
        output += "<tr><td>";
        output += obj.location;
        output += "</td><td>";
        output += obj.city;
        output += "</td><td>";
        output += obj.phone;
        output += "</td><td>";
        output += obj.vaccinetype;
        output += "</td><td>";
        let coordinate = obj.point.coordinates.reverse().toString();
        output += <a href='https:www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=' + coordinate + ' target=_blank'> Click here to see map </a>;
        output += "</td></tr>";            
        
    }
}
document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML = output;
}
```

Comment: oh that works, but seems like the coordinates are not added to google map because when I click on any of the link, I still get my home location so it means coordinates are not working.

Comment: you need convert coordinates to string

Comment: got another error when I try this var map = obj.point{coordinates:[]};;  on the open bracket of {